# New Jersey Marriage Index

Tags: 20th-century, marriage-records, new-jersey

I found an entry for a 1923 marriage on the New Jersey Marriage Index. It references a VOL and Page #.  Where can I view the Volumes?

Answer (score 3):

According to the article in the FamilySearch Research Wiki, *New Jersey Vital Records* under the section [Marriage](https://www.familysearch.org/en/wiki/New_Jersey_Vital_Records#Marriage), some images are available to view (subscription required) at findmypast: [New Jersey Vital Records](https://search.findmypast.com/search-world-Records/new-jersey-vital-records). The description of the record set includes this note (open the section **Discover more about these records** under the search form):

> The New Jersey Vital Records collection has been digitised and transcribed by Findmypast in partnership with the Historical Society of Pennsylvania (HSP). The collection brings together a variety of record types from HSP’s archive.

[New Jersey's State Department of Health](https://www.nj.gov/health/vital/) says that marriages from 1923 are held at the [New Jersey State Archives](https://nj.gov/state/archives/index.html).  See the page [Marriage Record Search Request: May 1, 1848 - December 31, 1940](https://wwwnet-dos.state.nj.us/DOS_ArchivesDBPortal/index.aspx) to order a copy of the record. If you live in the area, and would like to research at the Archives in person, see the page [Planning Your Visit](https://www.nj.gov/state/archives/directions.html).